# Alignment of nodes in tikz picture

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to align "Core 1" in the following picture with the rest of the nodes:

[image]

However, for some reason, the Core 1 node seems to be offset compared to the rest of the nodes, and I am unsure why that is the case. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, calc, chains, positioning, shapes}

\tikzset
{
core/.style = {
    rectangle,
    rounded corners,
    draw           = black, thick,
    text width     = 5em, 
    minimum height = 3em,
    align=center,
    on chain
            },
cache/.style = {
    core,
    draw           = gray,
            }
}% end of tikzset

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 4mm, 
start chain = going below ]
\node [core, minimum width=4cm,midway]           (c1)  {Core 1};
\node [cache]  (l11) {L1 data\\  32 KB}; 
\node [cache,right=of l11]  (l12) {L1 \\  32 KB}; 
%shared l2 cache
\path   let \p1 = ($(l12.east)-(l11.west)$), 
        \n1 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)} in
    node [core,minimum width = \n1,
         below=of $(l11.south)!0.5!(l12.south)$]    (l13) {L2 \\ 256 KB};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! This code is very incomplete. Even if one adds a document class, loads `tikz` and `\begin{document}`, the very first path requires a node `l11` which is not defined. Please provide a complete compilable code. BTW, you can align this node very easily with `\path (left node) -- (right node) node[midway,above=...,...]{...};`. But I assume your problem is that you put the nodes `on chain` so they get conflicting placement information, which moves your node in the way you show.

Comment: That is, probably the problem is solved by removing `on chain` from the definition of `core`. Reliable statements, however, will require a complete example.

Comment: The code should compile now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways to fix this, this is one. One problem was the `on chain` key.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, positioning}

\tikzset
{
core/.style = {
    rectangle,
    rounded corners,
    draw           = black, thick,
    text width     = 5em, 
    minimum height = 3em,
    align=center,
            },
cache/.style = {
    core,
    draw           = gray,
            }
}% end of tikzset

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 4mm]
\node [core, minimum width=4.5cm,midway]           (c1)  {Core 1};
\node [cache,below=of c1.south west,anchor=north west]  (l11) {L1 data\\  32 KB}; 
\node [cache,below=of c1.south east,anchor=north east]  (l12) {L1 \\  32 KB}; 
%shared l2 cache
\path   let \p1 = ($(l12.east)-(l11.west)$), 
        \n1 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)} in
    node [core,minimum width = \n1,
         below=of $(l11.south)!0.5!(l12.south)$]    (l13) {L2 \\ 256 KB};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that in this case you do not need to compute the width of the lower node, but I kept the computation as it may become relevant in other cases. You may also start with the middle layer nodes and construct the others with this width computation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, positioning}

\tikzset
{
core/.style = {
    rectangle,
    rounded corners,
    draw           = black, thick,
    minimum width    = 5em, 
    minimum height = 3em,
    align=center,
            },
cache/.style = {
    core,
    draw           = gray,
            }
}% end of tikzset

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 4mm]
\node [cache]  (l11) {L1 data\\  32 KB}; 
\node [cache,right=of l11]  (l12) {L1 \\  32 KB}; 
%shared l2 cache
\path   let \p1 = ($(l12.east)-(l11.west)$), 
        \n1 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)} in
    node [core,minimum width = \n1,
         below=of $(l11.south)!0.5!(l12.south)$]    (c2) {L2 \\ 256 KB}
    node [core,minimum width = \n1,
         above=of $(l11.north)!0.5!(l12.north)$]    (c1) {Core 1}
         ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This will continue to give good results even if the cache nodes become wider.

Answer (score 2):

A small variation of other answers:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
  node distance = 4mm and 0mm,
box/.style args = {#1/#2}{draw=#1, minimum width=#2,
                          rounded corners=5, minimum height=10mm,
                          align=center},
box/.default    = gray/22mm
                        ]
\node (n1) [box=black/50mm]  {L2\\256 Kb};
\node (n21)[box, above right=of n1.north west] {L1 data\\32 Kb};
\node (n22)[box, above  left=of n1.north east] {L1 \\32 Kb};
\node (n3) [box=black/50mm, above=of n1 |- n21.north] {Core 1};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Below is code from my friend. His code is short and simple (I can not make it simpler). Is it right that we should code with elegant simplicity?

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[every node/.style={draw,rounded corners=5,minimum height=10mm,align=center}]
(0,0) node[minimum width=5cm]{Core 1}
(-1.5,-1.5) node[minimum width=2cm,draw=gray]{L1 data\\32 Kb}
(1.5,-1.5) node[minimum width=2cm,draw=gray]{L1\\32 Kb}
(0,-3) node[minimum width=5cm]{L2\\256 Kb};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```